# script arguments in my tradingview script

Tags: pine-script

im getting this error back from my script
line 47: The arguments 'maxval', 'minval', and 'step' cannot be used with the input() function. You can use the input.int() or input.float() functions to specify a range of input data values.

line 47    rsiOverbought = input.int(60, title = "RSI Overbought", minval = 0, maxval = 50, type = input.integer)

Answer (score 2):

In Pine Script V5 there is no `type` or `minval` parameters of `input()` function.
You need to specify type of the input by calling corresponding function -- `input.int()` for integers, `input.float()` for float values.

Correct syntax is:

```
input.int(defval, title, options, tooltip, inline, group, confirm) → input int
```

or

```
rsiOverbought = input.int(60, title = "RSI Overbought", minval = 0, maxval = 50)
```

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input{dot}int](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input%7Bdot%7Dint)